# Summarize CPU load for a full process tree in htop or other tool

Tags: cpu-load, htop

I want to see the full load MS teams creates, which has plenty of threads.

I already tried the tree view but the values from (1) are not added up in (2)

[image: htop1]
Can this be seen in htop or another nice tool?

*Edit* With "H" hotkey it still does not sum up everything

[image: htop2]

Comment: Does this help you? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471925

Comment: @Daniel thanks, I edited my question

Comment: A few Qs for context :1.) Does the ubuntu instance that is pictured have multiple sessions? (2.) If so, would more than one acct have an associated Teams process running? (3.) What app is making the process? Is it Teams or a VS Code ext?

Comment: The reason I am asking is because process list/action type CLI programs like `ps`, `top`, `htop`, `pgrep/pkill`, etc. usually will not show processes owned by other users, except for root-owned application processes, even if they launch with 'sudo' or from root acct (in other words, user A cannot see processes owned by user B, even if user A is root user). Not sure if htop is like this or not. If so, it will likely be documented in the `htop` man-page(s). I am fuzzy on the details myself atm, Just wanted to mention it so as to give you a new direction in which to look for an answer.

Comment: The Ubuntu instance has only one Gnome session. I am running teams as a single user, but I am also okay with using `sudo` to find more information. VS code is not in use.

Answer (score 3):

If you *need* a tool that does this, and frequently updates the info as `htop`, there *might* be no answer.
But if you are ok with executing a command and getting the result, as a snapshot, there are a few options.

One way is by processing the output of "the basic command" `ps`

```
$ ps -eo user,pid,ppid,pcpu,command
```

There are two ways to process the information.

**The simple method**

`grep` all lines with a given command, and sum `pcpu` usage.
E.g., for `firefox` with this simple version (you don't need `pid,ppid`)

```
$ ps -eo pcpu,command --sort -pcpu | grep firefox | awk '{p=$1 ; sum +=p} END {print sum}'
```

This method could give a result that might be off the actual target, due to:

1. Two separate processes with the same name, overestimating the actual result. Sometimes you may know if you are in one such case, and if so this *might* not be an issue.
2. Child processes not `grep`ped (I am not certain this could ever happen), underestimating the actual result.

The method below takes care of both potential issues.

**The complete method**

Navigate the process tree, starting with the PID (process ID, say, 10000) of your target process of interest.
You would then `grep` all other processes which have PPID (parent process ID) 10000, and record their PIDs.
Recursively obtain the whole tree, and add all values of `pcpu`.

You would have to write a small program for this.
I am not certain some items included in this sum would not be included in *the simple way* above.

**Notes** on "the basic command":

1. It is important to list `command` (or `cmd`, `args`). Column `comm` lists the process name, which may be different (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257518/ps-what-is-the-difference-between-o-comm-and-o-command)). For instance, `firefox` launches many `Web Content` processes, and this [teases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209689/sum-the-memory-usages-of-all-the-processes-of-a-program#comment1261211_209915) [the excellent tool](https://lwn.net/Articles/387202/) `atop` + <kbd>P</kbd>, e.g.
2. For other interesting analyses you could add `,size,%mem` as columns to show and process. See also below.

**The memory-side of resources usage**

There is an extensive "discussion" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-can-i-measure-the-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process), which applies to memory usage.
I am not sure if any of the claims there apply in any *similar* way (even considering the differences cpu usage vs. memory usage) here.

**Related**:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209689/sum-the-memory-usages-of-all-the-processes-of-a-program
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55148/top-htop-group-process-by-command/471925#471925
3. https://www.networkworld.com/article/3516319/showing-memory-usage-in-linux-by-process-and-user.html

Answer (score 1):

I now stumbled across `gotop` which provides exactly that function in the default view.

Install instructions are at https://github.com/xxxserxxx/gotop

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxserxxx/gotop/master/scripts/download.sh | bash && chmod +x gotop && sudo mv gotop /usr/local/bin/
```

As this pipes a remote source to your shell, make sure to verify the contents of the link first.

When started it looks like this. The processes box in the bottom right summarizes the CPU load and mem usage per executable.

[image: Screenshot of gotop, showing 4.1% total CPU load by teams]

Answer (score 0):

Based on sancho.s answer this is fair enough for me:

```
watch -n 1 'ps -eo pcpu,command --sort -pcpu | grep teams | awk "{p=\$1 ; sum +=p} END {print sum}"'
```

It prints the CPU load of all teams processes every secound (side note: for me it's always around 78%, even idle, which is crazy, but off topic here)

Or we can produce a log of the CPU load over time:

```
while sleep 1; do echo -n `date +"%H:%M:%S;" `; ps -eo pcpu,command --sort -pcpu | grep teams | awk "{p=\$1 ; sum +=p} END {print sum}"; done
```